# Can we add input text field in Lightning Datatable in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

Like in the below image in Quantity columns, I need to add input text field so that user can enter value in it.

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes its possible, but what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming you are using Aura, yes you can. Fist you would need please find code snippets below.

CMP file:

```
<div style="height: 300px">
                <lightning:datatable
                    keyField="Id"
                    columns="{!v.orderLabels}"
                    data="{!v.orders}"
                    hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                    minColumnWidth="120"
                    errors="{!v.errors}"
                    draftValues="{!v.draftValues}"
                    onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                    onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                    showRowNumberColumn="false"
                />
            </div>
```

JS to prepare the table on init and set which fields are editable:

```
setTableLabels: function(component) {

        let action = component.get("c.getOrderLabels");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                var labelsMap = response.getReturnValue();
                var moreInfoLabel = $A.get("$Label.c.CM_More_Info");

                component.set("v.orderLabels", [
                    {label: labelsMap.OrderLine, type: "button", typeAttributes:{
                        label: moreInfoLabel,
                        name: "showOrderLine",
                        disabled: false
                    }},
                    {label: labelsMap.Name, fieldName: "Name", type: "text"},
                    {label: labelsMap.RecipientName, fieldName: "recipient", type: "text"},
                    {label: labelsMap.OrderType, fieldName: "OrderType__c", type: "text"},
                    {label: labelsMap.Status, fieldName: "Status__c", type: "text"},
                    {label: labelsMap.OrderPeriodStartDate, fieldName: "OrderPeriodStartDate__c", type: "date"},
                    {label: labelsMap.OrderPeriodEndDate, fieldName: "OrderPeriodEndDate__c", type: "date"},
                    {label: labelsMap.TotalAmount, fieldName: "TotalAmount__c", type: "currency"},
                    {label: labelsMap.CancelledDate, fieldName: "CancelledDate__c", type: "date"},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingZipPostalCode, fieldName: "ShippingZipPostalCode__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingStreet2, fieldName: "ShippingStreet2__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingStreet1, fieldName: "ShippingStreet1__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingStateProvince, fieldName: "ShippingStateProvince__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingCountry, fieldName: "ShippingCountry__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true},
                    {label: labelsMap.ShippingCity, fieldName: "ShippingCity__c", type: "text", editable: "true", hideDefaultActions: true}
                ]);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

JS to handle the save actions:

```
handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var draftValues = event.getParam('draftValues');
        var action = component.get("c.updateOrders");
        action.setParams({"orders": draftValues});
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                helper.showToastMessage(component, "Success!", "Order information updated successfully.", "success");
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            } else {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.log(errors);
                helper.showToastMessage(component, "Error! Can't update record.", errors[0].message, "error");
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

There are more details, but I think this could give you a good start.

Comment: Hi Boris - Thank you so much for the response. It works..

Comment: This doesn't really embed the "input text box" within the cell, correct? the solution is just basic inline edit?

Comment: Yes I think so.